# Ignore some folders in os.listdir(path) Python

Tags: python

My python script executes a call to `os.listdir(path)` where the path contains folders that I need to work on one by one. There are a few folders that need special treatment and need to be out of the list.

How can I exclude those folders from the list returned by `os.listdir(path)`?

Comment: exclude them from being worked on?

Comment: *How can I exclude those folders from the list* remove them from said list? list.remove() or list comprehension should do the job

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ignored = {"folder_one", "folder_two", "folder_three"}
folders = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x not in ignored]
```

Comment: In what way could we upgrade this to accept regex or a partial match?  Anything I can think of would make this much larger/more complicated.  Is there a simple way you can think of? Thanks

Comment: @Dylan Let say for example you want to exclude all files starting with "not". First, create your regex pattern: `reg = re.compile('^not*')`. Then, use a similar list comprehension: `[x for x in os.lisdir(path) if not reg.match(x)]`.

Comment: @Delgan Brilliant.  Thanks!