# how to get rid of desktop.ini with python's os.listdir() method of any windows folder

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-os, listdir

I'm using windows server 2016. I didn't have this issue earlier. I get the desktop.ini file listed when I run the command below.

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

The same folder is being used by another program. I don't know if that is affecting this behavior. Still, I don't want the desktop.ini file in the second program. How can I achieve this?

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
lst = list(set(os.listdir()) - {'desktop.ini', 'whatever.ini'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a list, you can simply remove `desktop.ini` everytime

```py
import os as OS
items = OS.listdir()
items.remove('desktop.ini')
```

Or you can list the items which you want to [ignore or remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32334692/16406491) from the list,

```py
import os as OS
items = OS.listdir()
items_not_required = {'desktop.ini', 'someotherthing'}
[items.remove(x) for x in items if x not in items_not_required]

# OR

items_clean = set(items) - set(items_not_required)
```

Comment: using set of ignored files  `{'desktop.ini', 'someotherthing'}` instead of list of ignored files would be better option.

Comment: `list.remove()` always returns None, so items will be None always

Comment: Thanks for the input :-). I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path 
[x for x in os.listdir() if x != 'desktop.ini' and Path(x).is_file()]
```

Or if you want the absolute filepath:

```
from pathlib import Path 
[str(Path(x).absolute()) for x in os.listdir() if x != 'desktop.ini' and Path(x).is_file()]
```